# Facebook and Twitter Share Error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, social-framework

I'm getting this error when Trying to share on facebook or twitter.

```
2015-04-12 17:49:42.208 TestShareApp[1069:30252] *** Assertion failure in -[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UIColor.m:1448
2015-04-12 17:49:42.359 TestShareApp[1069:30252] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110424c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fce0bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110424aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f24298f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000110c8379a -[UIColor encodeWithCoder:] + 972
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010f1f13e5 _encodeObject + 1120
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010f1f0c49 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 162
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000110f842f7 -[_UIAppearanceRecorder _recordInvocation:withClassName:containerClassNames:traitCollection:selectorString:forRemoteProcess:] + 1915
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110f7ef5d __54+[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:]_block_invoke + 907
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110364656 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011036455c -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 204
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110f7ebc0 +[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:] + 137
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011114897d UIViewServiceCurrentAppearanceSerializedRepresentations + 77
    13  UIKit                               0x000000011103bcc9 +[_UIRemoteViewController _requestViewController:traitCollection:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:service:connectionHandler:] + 232
    14  UIKit                               0x000000011103bbaa +[_UIRemoteViewController requestViewControllerWithService:connectionHandler:] + 91
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110f13db8 __117-[NSExtension(UIViewControllerAdditions) instantiateViewControllerWithInputItems:listenerEndpoint:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 621
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011220e186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011222d614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112215a1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011038c1f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011034ddcb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011034d366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113f81a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000110a4d900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    24  TestShareApp                           0x000000010e38d457 main + 135
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112261145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

and here is my facebook and twitter actionsheet code

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

    if buttonIndex == 1 { // Facebook

        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {

            var controller = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)

            controller.setInitialText(shareText)
            controller.addURL(NSURL(string: appUrl) )

            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            controller.completionHandler = { (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) -> Void in
                switch result {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled:
                    println("fb cancel")
                case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done:
                    println("done")
                }
            }

        } else {

            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Facebook Account", message: "Oops, you've not added facebook account in your iphone settings", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
            alert.show()

        }



    } else if buttonIndex == 2 { // Twitter

        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) {

            var controller = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter)

            controller.setInitialText(shareText)
            controller.addURL(NSURL(string: appUrl) )

            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            controller.completionHandler = { (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) -> Void in
                switch result {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled:
                    println("fb cancel")
                case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done:
                    println("done")
                }
            }


        } else {

            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Twitter Account", message: "Oops! Looks like you've not added Twitter account in your settings", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")
            alert.show()
        }

    }
}
```

same code works fine on my other apps. Not sure why this is happeing when I click or either facebook or twitter.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. From the Mian Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint. Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint **click debug continue** a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and **more error info**. Add that and an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages to the question.

Comment: all i get is "(lldb)"

Comment: I'm also receiving this exact crash, did you get to the bottom of it, @user528432?