# iPhone app crash: UIKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

**Update 29th October 2015**: Might have possibly found the cause of this. I'm creating a gradient layer according to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23074591/4027036) - it works perfectly fine for me and everyone else I've tested with, but might other people have problems with it?

```
CAGradientLayer * g  = [CAGradientLayer layer];
UIColor * colourFrom = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.7 blue:0.3  alpha:1.0];
UIColor * colourTo   = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.8 blue:0.4 alpha:1.0];

g.frame        = self.view.bounds;
g.cornerRadius = 10;
g.startPoint   = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
g.endPoint     = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
g.colors       = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[colourFrom CGColor],
                                           (id)[colourTo CGColor],
                                           nil];
```

---

**Update 27th October 2015**: Still seeing these crashes coming in from Crashlytics.

---

**Update 26th October 2015**: I found [this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589439/facebook-and-twitter-share-error-swift) which seems to be exactly the same issue as I am having (but with no answers..), however they are using Facebook/Twitter action sheets which I am not. Just something to help diagnose the issue.

---

Have just released an app to the App Store and we are seeing a small percentage of users (~2%) with this crash in Crashlytics:

It appears that it's only appearing with **iOS 9**, but it's happening across **all devices**.

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.

Personally I am running an iPhone 6 with 9.1 and am not experiencing the issue. I have also tried in Simulators and again no issues, so I am not sure of how this bug is actually cropping up. The stack trace from Crashlytics is below.

It seems as though a `UIColor` is being added to a `NSDictionary` without being encoded, but I'm not doing that anywhere in the app. It also seems as though it might have something to do with `UIRemoteViewController`, but I'm not using that in the app (unless logging in with Facebook causes that - I have tried logging in with Facebook on the phone and simulators, but again I cannot get this error to appear).

Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing this?

---

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 6512725832 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                6869942144 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 6512725528 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     6528403996 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          6606881444 -[UIColor encodeWithCoder:]
5  Foundation                     6528169072 _encodeObject
6  Foundation                     6528197336 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:]
7  UIKit                          6609904352 -[_UIAppearanceRecorder _recordInvocation:withClassName:containerClassNames:traitCollection:selectorString:forRemoteProcess:]
8  UIKit                          6609884356 __54+[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:]_block_invoke
9  CoreFoundation                 6511594744 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke
10 CoreFoundation                 6511594448 -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
11 UIKit                          6609883592 +[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:]
12 UIKit                          6611900724 UIViewServiceCurrentAppearanceSerializedRepresentations
13 UIKit                          6610654700 +[_UIRemoteViewController _requestViewController:traitCollection:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:service:connectionHandler:]
14 UIKit                          6610654160 +[_UIRemoteViewController requestViewControllerWithService:connectionHandler:]
15 UIKit                          6609355772 __117-[NSExtension(UIViewControllerAdditions) instantiateViewControllerWithInputItems:listenerEndpoint:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke_2
16 libdispatch.dylib              6878402280 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
17 libdispatch.dylib              6878402216 _dispatch_client_callout
18 libdispatch.dylib              6878424496 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
19 CoreFoundation                 6512427512 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
20 CoreFoundation                 6512418912 __CFRunLoopRun
21 CoreFoundation                 6511561888 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
22 GraphicsServices               6701891720 GSEventRunModal
23 UIKit                          6602887164 UIApplicationMain
24 MyApp                          4296179280 main (main.m:16)
25 libdyld.dylib                  6878603448 start
```

---

**Update with code examples**

This is called in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
// Make the app look pretty
// Turn the status bar color white
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
// Nav bar: Background colour
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
// Nav bar: White text
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];
// Nav bar: Tint colour
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TintNavBar"]];
// Tab Bar: Background color
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
// Tab bar: Tint colour
[UITabBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientSmall"]];
// UIControlSegment: Change the colours to just white
// @url https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484829/4027036
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[Ui getColour:UI_BODY_PRIMARY]}
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Can you post the line of code where you are getting this crash?

Comment: @Sujania No, as I'm not sure where it is actually coming from - I cannot reproduce it, and the stack trace does not indicate where either.

Comment: as per my reading this is the error with UIApperence or [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per my readings this is the error with UIApperence or [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] in ios 6

so check with that in your code. if you have that code in your app then use the solid color.

here are few of the links from which i came up to this conclusion:

1) [IOS erro at Posting to Facebook with the native Share dialog - UICGColor encodeWithCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403890/ios-erro-at-posting-to-facebook-with-the-native-share-dialog-uicgcolor-encodew)

2)[UIApperance and various crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570766/uiapperance-and-various-crashes)

3)[UIApperance and various crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570766/uiapperance-and-various-crashes)

4)[iOS 6 MFMailComposeViewController: Only support RGBA or the White color space, this method is a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593299/ios-6-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-only-support-rgba-or-the-white-color-space-t)

Comment: It's possible, I am setting `colorWithPatternImage` in `UIApperence`… however the app is only available on iOS 7+, and Crashlytics is reporting it as only crashing on iOS 9 devices (9.0, 9.0.2, and 9.1).

Comment: will you please post some code about for which control you are setting UIAppearance . 

you can try setting appearance like this.

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: Sure, have amended my original post - it's at the bottom.

Comment: In stead of colorWithPatternImage can you try using colorwithRGB and check that app is crashing or not?

Comment: Well, yes, I could. The problem is that I am not experiencing the crash on any device I can lay my hands on. I would have to push the code change to the App Store and see what happens. I'l have to see if the designer/bosses are happy to try that experiment for a week.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that pattern colors can't be encoded via `UIColor's` implementation of `NSCoding`. Their color space is `kCGColorSpaceModelPattern` which, as the message says, breaks `NSCoding` and therefore isn't allowed.

This can be trivally proven by running this code:

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever"]];
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
```

This blows up in `[UIColor encodeWithCoder]` with the same assert failure.

As to  why `UIColors` are being encoded at all, that's less clear. Something to do with `_UIAppearanceRecorder` most likely, but lord knows what. Just stop using pattern colors and you should be fine.